# C++, Makefiles, headerfiles

Tags: makefile, header

I just spoke with someone today regarding Makefiles and headerfiles. 
He claimed that the standard is to not include any .h files inside a makefile, and that all #include should be done inside .cpp, not the .h files.

Do you guys agree with this statement or is this one of those that can be done either way? I've found a mixture of opinions online.

Comment: When you say *"include a .h file inside a makefile"*, is that what you actually mean? Because that doesn't make any sense; C++ code and Make code have different syntax, they don't mix. As for `#include` not being done in .h files, your friend is very, very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Header files dependencies should end up being used by the Makefile, but only indirectly.  The header file dependencies will typically be generated automatically in some way.  For example, gcc has the -MD option to generate .d files which have the header dependencies.  Those .d files can be used by your Makefile with an `include`.  This means that you won't have to actually type the header file dependencies yourself, even though they are effectively in the Makefile.

If you didn't have a way to generate the header dependencies automatically, then you would have to do them manually.  Otherwise, `make` wouldn't know that it needs to rebuild the dependent object files when the header files changed.